# xlsxwriter creates empty rows between full rows

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsxwriter

i wrote a python code to generate an excel file from a csv file using xlsxwriter.
but the output is not what i wanted. i got empty rows between my data:

[image]

i don't know what make this happen in my code. i want to remove those empty lines like this:

[image]

```
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='cp1252') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

i appreciate your help.

Comment: I think its because reader include linefeeds and write also writes linefeeds, so you should remove linefeeds

Comment: Try `with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='cp1252', newline='') as f:`. The examples in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) use `newline=''`.

Comment: If that still does not work, open your CSV in a text editor. You may actually have blank lines in your CSV.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel you are right. my csv generetor creates empty lines: datas = {"big category":big_category,"small category":small_category,"Type de transaction":type_de_transaction,"Ville":city,"Secteur":secteur,"title":title,"description":description,"images":pics,"VENDRE PLUS VITE":vendre_plus_vite,"Prix":price}
  data.append(datas)
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  with open('sample.csv', 'a') as f:
   df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)

Comment: i fixed it adding newline='' to my open() function. thank you @JustinEzequiel . and can you please put your reply as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`with open('sample.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:`

The examples in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) use `newline=''`.